# passing data to a collection in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

So I am trying storing product types from a json file before trying to add them to a collection but am getting some strange results (as in I dont fully understand)

on my router page i setup a variable for cached products as well as product types

```
cachedProductTypes: null,
productType : {}, 
products : {},  

getProductTypes:
        function(callback)
        {
            if (this.cachedProductTypes !== null) {
                return callback(cachedProductTypes);
            }

            var self = this;

            $.getJSON('data/product.json',
                function(data)
                {
                    self.cachedProductTypes = data;
                    callback(data);
                }
            );
        },

parseResponse : function(data) {


          result = { prodTypes: [], products: [] };

          var type;
          var types = data.data.productTypeList;
          var product;
          var i = types.length;


         while (type = types[--i]) {
            result.prodTypes.push({ 
               id: type.id,
               name: type.name,
               longName: type.longName
               // etc.
            });
            while (product = type.productList.pop()) {
              product.productTypeId = type.id,
              result.products.push(product);
            }   
          };

          this.productType = result.prodTypes;
          console.log( "dan");
          this.products = result.products;      
    },
showProductTypes:function(){
        var self = this;

        this.getProductTypes(
            function(data)
            {
                self.parseResponse(data);

     var productTypesArray = self.productType;
     var productList=new ProductsType(productTypesArray);   
     var productListView=new ProductListView({collection:productList});

     productListView.bind('renderCompleted:ProductsType',self.changePage,self); 
     productListView.update();
    }
        );      
    }
```

when a user goes to the show product types page it runs the showProductsType function

So I am passing the products type array to my collection

on the collection page

```
      var ProductsType=Backbone.Collection.extend({

      model:ProductType,

      fetch:function(){
        var self=this;
        var tmpItem;
        //fetch the data using ajax



        $.each(this.productTypesArray, function(i,prodType){

            tmpItem=new ProductType({id:prodType.id, name:prodType.name,    longName:prodType.longName});
            console.log(prodType.name);
            self.add(tmpItem);
        });

        self.trigger("fetchCompleted:ProductsType");

      }
}); 
return ProductsType;
```

now this doesnt work as it this.productTypesArray is undefined if i console.log it.
 (how am I supposed to get this?)

I would have thought I need to go through and add each new ProductType.

the strange bit - if I just have the code

```
    var ProductsType=Backbone.Collection.extend({

      model:ProductType,

      fetch:function(){
        var self=this;
        var tmpItem;
        //fetch the data using ajax


        self.trigger("fetchCompleted:ProductsType");

      }
});


return ProductsType;
```

it actually adds the products to the collection? I guess this means I can just pass an array to the collection and do not have to add each productType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess this means I can just pass an array to the collection and do not have to add each productType?

Yes, you can pass an array to the [collection's constructor](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-constructor), and it will create the models for you.

As far as your caching code, it looks like the problem is here:

```
if (this.cachedProductTypes !== null) {
    return callback(cachedProductTypes);
}
```

The callback statement's argument is missing `this` - should be `return callback(this.cachedProductTypes)`.